# IFELSE statements within a query for ORDER BY

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I'm a bit confused on how IF ELSE statements work within a query.

Here's what I've been trying, plus variations of it, but I cannot seem to get it to bring back the results without an error...

```
$get_trash = mysql_query("SELECT *
                            FROM message
                           WHERE message_to_user_id = '$user_id'
                             AND message_to_user_id_hide = 1
                              OR message_from_user_id = '$user_id'
                             AND message_from_user_id_hide = 1
                          IF message_to_user_id = '$user_id'
                          THEN ORDER BY message_to_user_id_hide_time DESC
                          ELSEIF
                              message_from_user_id = '$user_id'
                          THEN ORDER BY message_from_user_id_hide_time DESC
                          ENDIF") or die(mysql_error());
```

Now I've used if else statements countless times with PHP but I've never used it WITHIN a mysql query so if anyone could shed some light on how you go about it then I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I do not think things like ordered projection can be done like that. You are better of constructing queries in PHP or having a set of queries do this job within a stored proc

Comment: You have problems in the WHERE clause -- it's not going to return correct results because the pairs (from, to) won't be obvious to the optimizer.  You need brackets around them.  Secondly, both the from and to fields will be in the resultset -- you can't order by both columns at once.  This query is better off as a UNION statement.

Comment: @OMG - Mysql and SQL Server and pretty much I suspect all DBMS put AND before OR, so it is `very obvious` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: @cyberwiki: Two vendors is your justification, along with the documentation from only one?  Truth is, you're just trolling me between this and reverting my question/tags.  I'm flattered that you think I deserve the attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
ORDER BY CASE '$user_id' WHEN message_to_user_id 
                         THEN message_to_user_id_hide_time 
                         WHEN message_from_user_id 
                         THEN message_from_user_id_hide_time END DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

It would help if you could say what your table looks like.  But, based on the SQL you've tried, I think what you're looking for is something along these lines:

```
 SELECT * FROM message WHERE
   (message_to_user_id = '$user_id' AND message_to_user_id_hide = 1)  OR
   (message_from_user_id = '$user_id' AND message_from_user_id_hide = 1)
 ORDER BY
    (CASE 
        WHEN message_to_user_id = '$user_id' 
        THEN message_to_user_id_hide_time 
        ELSE message_from_user_id_hide_time
     END) DESC
```

Comment: +1 I didn't look at the rest of the query this (or OMG's UNION) is probably what they need.

Comment: The brackets on the ORDER BY aren't necessary -- can't think of when they would be on a CASE statement to the optimizer, only helps readability.

Comment: The brackets on the ORDER BY are for clarity only, but the brackets in the WHERE clause are there because I can never remember which databases bind AND before OR and which bind left to right.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you very much, I'd not heard of he CASE function before. Are the brackets around the WHERE clause needed, cause it works either way when I test it out?

Comment: @cyberwiki: not in one product I use on an almost daily basis, which binds left to right.   Wish it were, but it's not.

Comment: The brackets around the WHERE clause are not necessary in MySQL because MySQL will correctly bind the ANDs before the ORs.  But, as in PHP, they don't hurt and do make your intent completely clear to the next programmer to come along.